# Can I disable "Display visual cues" by default in Avogadro?

Tags: software

These huge arrows are very annoying to me. I disable them every time I open Avogadro. Is there a way to disable them permanently?

Comment: Since you seem to have many questions about Avogadro, is there a reason you aren't using the Avogadro mailing list?

Answer (score 5):

Sure. There's a big checkbox in the Navigate Tool settings:

[image]

When you quit, the settings should be remembered for next launch.

If not, please e-mail the [Avogadro](http://lists.sourceforge.net/mailman/listinfo/avogadro-discuss) mailing list and we can figure out what's going on.